# How do I pass data to props.children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Pretty new to react native...

Im trying to loop over my this.props.children in order to pass a string to them which is defined in my parent... is this possible without having those childs defined in the render method ?

```
<OwnRenderer passMe = "string...">
    <OwnText/>
</OwnRenderer>
```

The OwnRenderer should pass the prop-string towards all its children...
The OwnRenderer does not know which childs he's gonna render, so its not possible to pass the props directly by ""...

I tried to loop over the childs to pass that string directly, but this sadly didn't worked.

```
this.props.children.map((x) => x.passed = this.props.passMe);
```

Somehow it just didn't changed the state... how would you guys do this in a easy and understandable way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use React top level api: [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

Define

```js
interface Props {
  ChildName: React.ReactElement,
}

{React.cloneElement(ChildName, {
  propsName: {
    propsAttr: value,
    propsAttr2: value,
  }
})}
```

Usage

```js
<ParentComponent
  ChildName={
    <YourChildComponent />
  }
/>
```

Comment: Any example with a array of childs ? :)

Comment: @genaray updating